# How to set the position of cones to a vector3 variable? (three.js)

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, geometry, position

Basically I want to set the position of a cone to a vector3 variable.

I know I can set the position of a Geometry with:
`coneTop.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );`

But want I want is to set the position of the cone to a vector3 I defined.
`let endVector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 150, 0 );`

So I did this:
`coneTop.position.set( endVector );`

I don't get an error in the console but the cone just doesn't appear in the scene.
Can someone tell me why this is the case?

If you need more Information or code just tell me what you need.
I am very thankful for any help I can get on this.

Sincerely,
Philip

Comment: Try this: `coneTop.position.copy( endVector );`. `.set()` expects three float values in its parameters, whereas you pass one `THREE.Vector3`.

Comment: Yes, thanks @prisoner849 I fixed it.
There is also a forum post where someone had the same question as me.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11372